# When the app made with Expo is open on, it does not go to sleep mode, it stays open all the time

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, expo-av

I uploaded the app to the appstore. According to the feedback I get, the screen stays on all the time. How can I solve this problem?

I wondered if the screen stays on because the devclient is open. But if I'm not mistaken, the applications we developed before were closing. I am using expo-av in the app. Could it be that it pretends to play sound and is trying to keep it on? But I removed all the code in the app.jsx file, only  remained. But still the screen stays on. There is nothing in imports except react. What could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's on by default https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20328

What I do is

```
KeepAwake.deactivateKeepAwake()
```

As documented in [KeepAwake](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/keep-awake/)

Answer (score 1):

I added the following control to **package.json**.

```
"expo": {
   "autoLink": {
     "exclude": ["expo-keep-awake"]
   }
}
```

Then I added the following command in useEffect in **app.jsx**.

```
deactivateKeepAwake();
```

- First of all, I got the build like this and tried it. Now the screen goes into sleep mode.
- Then I removed the change in package.json and got build again and tried it. The screen goes to sleep again.
- And finally I re-added the change in package.json. Then I removed the deactivateKeepAwake() command in app.jsx. This is how I got the build and the screen goes to sleep again.

In all three scenarios, the screen goes to sleep.