# Expo App doesn't go to sleep after publishing an OTA

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

After updating my expo app to expo-48 version, I found out that after publishing an update via `expo-cli publish --release-channel <RELEASE_CHANNEL>` It stays awake all the time and never goes to sleep.

If instead of publishing the changes I rebuild the application via `eas build --profile <EAS_PROFILE_NAME>`, there is no problem and the app goes to sleep as expected.

I was wondering if anyone has encountered a similar issue or knows how to solve it.

Searching around I found the following posts/issues, but they seem to be a different problem.

- https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20328
- [When the app made with Expo is open on, it does not go to sleep mode, it stays open all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74433905/)

Some of the things that i tried are:

- Removing `activateKeepAwakeAsync()` from my appEntry.js
- Using `deactivateKeepAwakeAsync()` in my appEntry.js

But after publishing some changes, it will stay awake all the time.